# Let $n=km \in \mathbb N$, show $\left(2^{k}+1\right)\left(2^{k m-k}-2^{k m-2 k}+2^{k m-3 k}-2^{k m-4 k}+\cdots+1\right)=\left(2^{k m}+1\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Let $n=km,k,m \in \mathbb N$ and let $m$ be odd.
Show $\left(2^{k}+1\right)\left(2^{k m-k}-2^{k m-2 k}+2^{k m-3 k}-2^{k m-4 k}+\cdots+1\right)=\left(2^{k m}+1\right)$.

Important: Remember to consider where you use that $m$ is odd. **(I can't figure out where I'm using this property of $m$(?!))**

Here are my calculations
$$\begin{array}{r}{\left(2^{k}+1\right)\left(2^{k m-k}-2^{k m-2 k}+2^{k m-3 k}-2^{k m-4 k}+\cdots+1\right)=} \\ {2^{k m}-2^{k m-k}+2^{k m-2 k}-2^{k m-3 k}+\cdots+2^{k}} \\ {+\left(2^{k m-k}-2^{k m-2 k}+2^{k m-3 k}-2^{k m-4 k}+\cdots+1\right)=} \\ {\cdot \cdot+1=} \\ {2^{k m}+1}\end{array}$$

The calculations are simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we multiply we get:

$$2^{km} + (2^{km-1} - 2^{km-1}) - (2^{km-2} - 2^{km - 2}) + ... - (2^{k} - 2^{k}) + 1 = 2^{km} + 1$$

because the terms are pairwise canceling. If $m$ was even, you would have a different sign at the end, so it would be $2^{km} - 1$.

Comment: Thanks! I also wrote this in my assignment but in the feedback I got it said that I have not mentioned how I used the property of m.

Comment: @Xenusi check out my edit, added note about $m$.

Comment: Thanks. This I did not write. That's probably the case why the instructor was not satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

$m$ is odd is used in the base case $m = 1$ of the inductive proof below (OP has  $\,x = 2^k$). If $m$ is even then the division terminates at $\,m=0\,$ leaving remainder $\,x^m+1\,\bmod\, x+1\, =\, (-1)^m+1 = \color{#0a0}2\,$ (vs. $0$) yielding an additional final term $\,\color{#0a0}2/(x+1),\,$ e.g. $\ (x^2+1)/(x+1)\, =\, x-1 + \color{#0a0}2/(x-1)$

Base case: $\, m = 1:\ \dfrac{x+1}{x+1} = \color{#c00}1$

$\!\begin{align}\text{Inductive step:}\ \ \ \ \ \dfrac{x^m+1}{x+1} &=\ x^{m-1} - x^{m-2} + \dfrac{x^{m-2}+1}{x+1}\\[.2em] &=\, x^{m-1}-x^{m-2} + (x^{m-3}-x^{m-4} + \cdots +\color{#c00} 1)\ \ \rm by\ induction\end{align}$

That this was not clear seems to indicate that you have not adequately understood the induction implied by the informal ellipses used in your sketched proof. One of the purposes of *formal* inductive proofs is to help prevent our *intuition* from leading us astray in this manner.